# Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I try to edit my items in React and the function didn't work
I know I miss something, but I don't know what I miss and I tried more than 12 hours to fixed it.

I use  `event.preventDefault();` on another function and everything is fine but in the code below I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function
```

My code:

```
update(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const update_i = {
    id: this.state.id,
    x1: this.state.x1,
    x2: this.state.x2,
    x3: this.state.x3
  };

  Axios.put("/item", update_i)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data != null) {
        this.setState({ "show": true, "method": "put" });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ "show": false }), 3000);
      } else {
        this.setState({ "show": false });
      }
    });

  this.setState(this.id ,this.x1, this.x2, this.x3);
};
```

Comment: Can you please show the part of your app where you're using the `update` method?

Comment: ` <td><button  onClick={() => this.update(data.id)}>Edit</button></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means when you call `update()` function you need to pass the event like this: `update(event)`. In react it is usually used like this on event handlers:

```
(event) => update(event)
```

Comment: i have id of the item i need updated 
what  i should pass

Comment: ``` <td><button  onClick={(event) =>this.update(data.id,event)}>EEEE</button></td>```

same error

Comment: The order of the parameters matters here. If you pass it it like `event => this.update(data.id, event)` then you need to have the definition like `update(id, event) { ... }` but you could also define it the other way round - just need to have the right order.